# Prove: for $n\ge1$, $x_n\gt x_{n+1}\gt \sqrt{N}$ and $x_n-\sqrt{N} \le \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{({x_0 - \sqrt{N}})^2} {x_0}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $N>0$, $x_0>0$, and

$$x_{n+1} = \frac12 \left(\frac{N}{x_n} + x_n\right), \qquad n\ge0.$$

Prove: for $n\ge1$, $x_n > x_{n+1} > \sqrt{N}$ and

$$x_n-\sqrt{N} \le \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{(x_0 - \sqrt{N})^2} {x_0}$$

Can someone explain to me what this question is asking and how I can prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have a positive number $N$. Consider the sequence $x_0, x_1, x_2, ...$ s.t.

1. The first term of the sequence, $x_0$, is positive.
2. The sequence $x_0, x_1, x_2, ...$ satisfies the recurrence relation $x_{n+1} = \frac12(\frac{N}{x_n} + x_n)$.

---

To understand the sequence better, note that:

1. $x_n$ is a **positive** sequence ($x_0 > 0 \to x_1 > 0 \to x_2 > 0 \to ...$).
2. $x_n$ is a **decreasing** sequence (seen by the first property we must later prove).
3. $x_n$ is **bounded below** by $\sqrt{N}$ (seen by the first property we must later prove).
4. $x_n$ converges to its infimum, some number $\ge \sqrt{N}$ (monotone convergence theorem)
5. $x_n$'s infimum, and hence limit, is $\sqrt{N}$ (Solve $L = \frac12(\frac{N}{L} + L)$ to guess $\sqrt{N}$, then prove using infimum definition )

---

Now we are tasked to show 2 more recurrence relations:

1. for $n\ge1$ (What about 0?), $x_n\gt x_{n+1}\gt \sqrt{N}$, that is,

$$x_1\gt x_{2}\gt \sqrt{N}$$

$$x_2\gt x_{3}\gt \sqrt{N}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$x_n\gt x_{n+1}\gt \sqrt{N}$$

$$\vdots$$

Prove this by using induction. I believe you're going to have to use the quadratic formula somewhere. If it helps you can rewrite

$$x_n\gt x_{n+1}\gt \sqrt{N}$$

as

$$x_n^2\gt x_{n+1}^2\gt N$$

2. (for $n \ge 1$? What about 0?) $x_n-\sqrt{N} \le \frac{1}{2^n} * \frac{({x_0 - \sqrt{N}})^2} {x_0}$, that is

$$x_1-\sqrt{N} \le \frac{1}{2^1} * \frac{({x_0 - \sqrt{N}})^2} {x_0}$$

$$x_2-\sqrt{N} \le \frac{1}{2^2} * \frac{({x_0 - \sqrt{N}})^2} {x_0}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$x_n-\sqrt{N} \le \frac{1}{2^n} * \frac{({x_0 - \sqrt{N}})^2} {x_0}$$

$$\vdots$$

Prove this by using induction. If it helps you can rewrite

$$x_n-\sqrt{N} \le \frac{1}{2^n} * \frac{({x_0 - \sqrt{N}})^2} {x_0}$$

as

$$(x_n-\sqrt{N})^2 \le [\frac{1}{2^n} * \frac{({x_0 - \sqrt{N}})^2} {x_0}]^2$$

Comment: Possible flaw: Is $X_0 - \sqrt{N}$ positive? Is the first property really $n \ge 1$?